# Insert a function at runtime using 'dlfcn' library

Tags: c++, dll, jit

**temp.cpp**

```
void func()
{
    std::cout<<" I am in fun function " << std::endl;
}
```

**main.cpp**

```
#include<iostream>
#include <dlfcn.h>
using namespace std;

struct MyFunc {

    typedef void (*func_handle)(); //same signature as in the lib

    func_handle func;
    void *func_lib;

    MyFunc() {
        func_lib = dlopen("/home/dlopen/temp", RTLD_LAZY | RTLD_DEEPBIND);
        func = reinterpret_cast<func_handle>(dlsym(func_lib, "func"));
    }

    ~MyFunc() {
        dlclose(func_lib);
    }

};


int main()
{
    std::cout<<"I am in main function " << std::endl;
    std::system("g++ /home/dlopen/temp.cpp -o /home/dlopen/temp -shared -fPIC");
    MyFunc obj;
    obj.func();
    return 0;
}
```

**Output :**

```
I am in main function 
Segmentation fault
```

Not able to understand why it's giving a segmentation fault.

Comment: `dlopen` and `dlsym` can fail and return NULL. You should check them for failure.

Comment: @wohlstad thanks for pointing that out, missed it. 'dlsym' is coming out to be null in this case. But curious, why it's happening?

Comment: https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/extern-c-in-c/

Answer (score -1):

@instance
Proceed based on comment from "wohlstad".
I thought of sharing:

```
    temp1.cpp
    #include <iostream>
    using namespace std;
    #ifdef __cplusplus
    extern "C" {
    #endif
     void myfunction()
     {
            cout << "myfunction\n";
     }
    #ifdef __cplusplus
    }
    #endif
    
    main1.cpp
    #include <iostream>
    using namespace std;
    #include <dlfcn.h>
    typedef void(*FunPtr)();
    FunPtr CallMyFunction;
    int main()
    {
        // Always Rre-compile temp1.cpp/temp1.o/temp1.so
        system( "if [ -f temp1.o ];then rm temp1.o;fi;if [ -f temp1.so ];then rm temp1.so;fi;g++ -g -Wall -c temp1.cpp -o ./temp1.o;if [ 0 -eq $? ];then g++ -g -Wall temp1.o -o ./temp1.so -shared -fPIC;else g++ -c temp.cpp failed;fi;");
        void* SymTabHandler = dlopen( "./temp1.so", RTLD_LAZY);
        CallMyFunction = (FunPtr)dlsym( SymTabHandler, "myfunction");
        CallMyFunction();
        if ( NULL != CallMyFunction )
        {
                CallMyFunction = reinterpret_cast ( CallMyFunction );
                if ( NULL != CallMyFunction )
                {
                        CallMyFunction();
                }
                else
                {
                        cout << "reinterpret_cast failed DLERROR: " << dlerror() << endl;
                }
        }
        else
        {
                cout << "dlsym failed DLERROR: " << dlerror() << endl;
        }
        return 0;
    }
```

```
Sample output:<BR>
$ g++ -g -Wall main1.cpp -o ./a.out<BR>
$ ./a.out<BR>
myfunction<BR>
myfunction<BR>
$# I handled NULL exceptions and usage of shared object(.so/.sl/.dll), object(.o/.obj) and executable(a.exe/a.out) files.
```